# Как изменить значение Max Value, используя код c#, у объекта Slider в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, slider

пробовал это, но не получилось(

```
private void MaxValueSlider()
{
    slider.MaxValue = 100;
}
```

Comment: извините, я разобрался)  ошибка была в регистре, нужно писать maxValue, вместо MaxValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в регистре - нужно писать `maxValue`, вместо `MaxValue`:

```
private void MaxValueSlider()
{
    slider.maxValue = 100;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/391018)

Comment: @yolosora, это ответ. См. комментарий под вопросом.